# Prove that the zeros of the polynomial $P(z)=z^7+7z^4+4z+1$ lie inside the disk of radius $2$ centered at the origin.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification

> Prove that the zeros of the polynomial $P(z)=z^7+7z^4+4z+1$ lie inside the disk of radius $2$ centered at the origin.

Assuming the contrary that there exists an $|z|\geqslant2$ such that $P(z)=0$ I have that $$z^7+7z^4+4z+1 = 0 \implies 1+\frac{7}{z^3}+\frac{4}{z^6} +\frac{1}{z^7}=0 \implies 1+\frac{7}{8}+\frac{4}{64}+\frac{1}{128} = \frac{249}{128}\ne0$$

which is a contradiction so the zeros would lie inside the disk of radius $2$?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your reasoning? To me, it only indicates that $z = 2$ isn't a root.

Comment: There exists $|z| \ge 2$ such that ... does not mean $z=2$ has that property.

Comment: This is a complex analysis question?  What did you have just before it in the book?  There is a nice theorem that will do this for you...

Comment: This is a problem from a preparation book for the Putnam.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a solution, $|z^7|=|7z^4+4Z+1|$ Suppose that $|z|\geq 2$,

$2^7=128>7 \times 2^4 +4 \times  2+1=127$

Comment: This seems to assume that $|z|=2$, so I think you still need Rouche's theorem to conclude the result.

Answer (score 1):

For $\vert z \vert =2$ you have

$$\vert 7z^4 +4z+1\vert \le 121 \lt 128 = \vert z^7 \vert$$
Hence according to [Rouché’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem?wprov=sfti1) $P$ has seven zeros in the disk of radius equal to $2$.

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks for noticing the typo that is now corrected!